# Analytical solution for semidefinite program

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

How can I solve the following semidefinite program in an analytic way?

$\displaystyle \min\sum_{i=1}^{d} \mathcal{e}_i$

$S.t\thinspace\thinspace\begin{bmatrix}\mathcal{e_1}&0&0\\\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&\dots&\mathcal{e}_d\end{bmatrix}-A\succeq0$.

Where $A$ is the Adjacency Matrix of the graph

Comment: With the gershgorin circle theorem we get an upper bound of the sum of the degrees of the graph (i.e. $2$ times the number of edges) which is attained with the graph laplacian

Comment: Can you provide a formal solution?

Comment: No.  Note that my comment is not even an "informal solution".

Comment: It might help to consider the dual semidefinite program

Comment: SDP in what optimization variables?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo optimizing the capacity of each arch in the graph